# A different way to try to define a measure on the unit-circumference circle

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let **C** denote the Lie group (ℝ/ℤ, +), and let ℤ<sub>n</sub> denote the subgroup of **C** generated by [1/n].

Let (X,n) be an ordered pair where X ⊂ **C** is an *arbitrary* subset, and n ∊ ℤ+, such that that the set of images {g+X  |  g ∊ ℤ<sub>n</sub>} of X by the action of the group ℤ<sub>n</sub> **forms a partition of** **C**.

Call such an X an "1/n equal part" of **C**.

We now try to create a finitely additive measure  "from the top down" on **C** by assigning to each 1/n equal part X of **C** the value (X)  =  1/n.

Assume that, *for all positive integers* n, the assignment (X)  =  1/n is made for all (X,n) such that X is a 1/n equal part of **C**.

*Questions*:

1. Does  extend to a finitely additive measure on an algebra of sets containing all such X ?
2. What about a -additive measure on a -algebra of sets containing all such X ?
3. And if this is possible, can such a  extend ordinary Lebesgue measure?

Answer (score 2):

There is a finitely additive, translation invariant measure on the entire power set of $\mathbf C$ (see, for example, [Amenability, the ping-pong lemma, and the Banach–Tarski paradox](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/245b-notes-2-amenability-the-ping-pong-lemma-and-the-banach-tarski-paradox-optional)).  Clearly, it satisfies your desired condition (1).  Since rational-length, half-open ‘intervals’ in $\mathbf C$ are finite, disjoint unions of $1/n$-equal parts that are intervals for various $n$, and generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and since Lebesgue (I would rather say Haar) measure assigns measure $1/n$ to a $1/n$-equal part that is an interval, we have that any countably additive extension as in (2) extends Haar measure.  I suspect that a Vitali-type argument shows that no extension as in (2) exists, but I do not currently see it.