# If $A, B$ is a non-trivial partition of $S^1$, is it possible that $R_\theta(A) \cap B$ has measure zero for all rotations $R_\theta$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, haar-measure

This was previously posted to Math StackExchange. I was originally unsure whether it is suitable for posting here, but I've yet to get an answer there, so I'm just trying to see if people here can help.

As in the question title, let $A, B$ be a partition of the unit circle $S^1$, equipped with the Haar measure. Here, we *do not* require $A, B$ to be measurable. Also, assume neither $A$ nor $B$ is of measure zero, so they are either both non-measurable or both of positive measure. (Equivalently, they both have positive outer measure.) Is it possible, then, for $R_\theta(A) \cap B$ to be measurable and have Haar measure zero for all $\theta$, where $R_\theta$ is the rotation by degree $\theta$?

Comment: The mathstack post is at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4709229/if-a-b-is-a-non-trivial-partition-of-s1-is-it-possible-that-r-thetaa

Comment: Clearly, $A$ and $B$ cannot be then measurable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming the Continuum Hypothesis, the answer is yes.  On CH, the $\mathbf Q$-dimension of $\mathbf R$ has the cardinality of the first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$, so we can find a $\mathbf Q$-linear basis $e_\alpha, \alpha \in \omega_1$ of ${\bf R}$, and we can normalize $e_0=1$. Thus every irrational real number $x$ has a unique representation of the form
$$ x = \sum_{\alpha \leq \beta} q_\alpha e_\alpha\tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $0 < \beta < \omega_1$ and $q_\alpha, \alpha \leq \beta$ are rational numbers with all but finitely many $q_\alpha$ non-zero, and $q_\beta$ also non-zero.  In particular, $q_\beta$ is the final non-zero coefficient of $x$. We then assign $e^{2\pi i x}$ to lie in $A$ if $x$ is rational, or $x$ is irrational with representation \eqref{1} with $\nu_2(q_\beta)$ even, where $\nu_2(q_\beta) \in \mathbf Z$ is the number of times two divides the final non-zero coefficient $q_\beta$, and $e^{2\pi i x}$ to lie in $B$ if $x$ is irrational with representation \eqref{1} with $\nu_2(q_\beta)$ odd.  Since the final non-zero coefficient $q_\beta$ is unaffected by shifts by integers (or even rationals) on the irrationals, this is a well-defined partition of $S^1$.  By construction, if $z$ is not a root of unity, then $z$ lies in $A$ if and only if $z^2$ lies in $B$.  Because of this, neither $A$ nor $B$ can have measure zero (otherwise $S^1 = A \cup B$ would also have measure zero).

On the other hand, if $\theta = e^{2\pi i s}$ is an angle, then $s$ is a finite $\mathbf Q$-linear combination of the $e_\alpha$.  Such rotations do not affect the final non-zero coefficient $q_\beta$ in \eqref{1} unless $\beta$ is less than or equal to one of these $\alpha$ (or $x$ is rational), which only occurs countably often.  Thus $R_\theta(A) \cap B$ is countable (hence null) for all $\theta$.

Comment: The same argument seems to work under Martin's Axiom, as it implies that every set of reals of cardinality less than continuum is null.

Answer (score 8):

This question is explored in great generality by Laczkovich in

*Laczkovich, Miklós*, "[Two constructions of Sierpiński and some cardinal invariants of ideals](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-24/issue-2/Two-Constructions-of-Sierpi%C5%84ski-and-Some-CardinalInvariants-of-Ideals/rae/1285689143.full)", Real Anal. Exch. 24(1998-99), No. 2, 663-676 (1999), [MR1704742](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1704742), [Zbl 0964.03056](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0964.03056) (the paper is Open access at ProjectEuclid).

Sierpiński proved such a partition exists under CH, by an argument which immediately extends to any model where every set of reals of cardinality less than continuum is null (as Terry and Yair observed in the other answer). Laczkovich shows that there is no such partition in random real models (e.g., $L$ adjoined with $\omega_2$ random reals), so this problem is independent from ZFC.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\th\theta$This is a partial answer, showing that, if $R_\th(A)\cap B$ is measurable and has Haar measure $|\cdot|$ zero for all $\th$, then $A$ and $B$ cannot be measurable with $|A|>0$ and $|B|>0$.

Indeed, suppose the contrary (we do not need to assume here that $B$ is the complement of $A$). By the regularity of the Haar measure, there exist (say open) arcs $I$ and $J$ of the circle such that $|A\cap I|>|I|/2$ and $|B\cap J|>|J|/2$. Since $|A\cap I|,|I|,|B\cap J|,|J|$ depend continuously on the endpoints of the arcs $I$ and $J$, without loss of generality (wlog) $|I|$ and $|J|$ are rational numbers, say $p/q$ and $r/s$, respectively, for some natural $p,q,r,s$. Partitioning each of the arcs $I$ and $J$ into arcs of the same length $1/(qs)$, we see that wlog $|I|=|J|=1/(qs)$.

Renormalizing the Haar measure, assume wlog that $|I|=|J|=1$, so that $|A\cap I|>1/2$ and $|B\cap J|>1/2$. Also, the condition $|I|=|J|$ implies that $I=R_{-\th}(J)$ for some real $\th$, so that $|R_\th(A)\cap J|=|A\cap R_{-\th}(J)|=|A\cap I|$. So,
$$
\begin{split}
|R_\th(A)\cap B|&\ge|(R_\th(A)\cap J)\cap(B\cap J)| \\ 
&=|R_\th(A)\cap J|+|B\cap J|-|(R_\th(A)\cap J)\cup(B\cap J)| \\ 
&=|A\cap I|+|B\cap J|-|(R_\th(A)\cap J)\cup(B\cap J)| \\ 
&\ge|A\cap I|+|B\cap J|-|J| \\ 
&>1/2+1/2-1=0.
\end{split}
$$
So, $|R_\th(A)\cap B|>0$, a contradiction. $\quad\Box$

Comment: I know that a similar fact is true about positive-measure subsets of the real line.  It's no surprise that a fact about the real line would have an analogue on the circle; but do you know whether there is some general analogue of this result, say, for general compact groups? \\ By the way, your answer reminds me of techniques that seemed relevant for [A different way to try to define a measure on the unit-circumference circle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443357).  I gave a [partial answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/443362); maybe you can knock out the whole thing?

Comment: @LSpice : Thank you for your comment. I will have it in mind.

Comment: You are welcome, @IosifPinelis

Comment: Also, from the Fubini-Tonelli theorem one has $\int |R_\theta(A) \cap B|\ d\theta = |A| |B|$ for measurable $A,B$ (if we normalize the unit circle to have total mass one), which is another way to handle this case.  (The counterexample in my answer is inspired in part by one of the standard counterexamples to the Fubini-Tonelli theorem based on the first uncountable ordinal.)

Comment: @TerryTao : Thank you for your comment. Your proof is much nicer! So, it seems to be much easier to deal with the circle than with the real line -- do you think this is so indeed?

Comment: @IosifPinelis, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447925/if-a-b-is-a-non-trivial-partition-of-s1-is-it-possible-that-r-thetaa#comment1157518_447929), measure-theoretically, isn't $\mathbb R$ just countably many copies of $S^1$?  Of course this isn't true group-theoretically, but, for translation on $\mathbb R$ by a fixed amount, only finitely many copies of $S^1$ can interact.

Comment: @LSpice : I am not sure how to use your latter comment. Could you please elaborate on it?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Actually, the Fubini-Tonelli argument works in any unimodular locally compact group (I realized afterwards that there is no need to normalize the Haar measure).  Another way of thinking about it is that $\|1_A * 1_{-B}\|_{L^1} = \|1_A\|_{L^1} \|1_{-B}\|_{L^1}$.

Comment: @TerryTao : Thank you again. Yes, it is still just as simple for any unimodular locally compact group!

Comment: @IosifPinelis, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1157537), probably it's not interesting in light of @‍TerryTao's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/posts/comments/1157539), but what I was thinking was: if we have a partition of $\mathbb R$, then we can use a measure-space isomorphism $S^1 \cong [0, 1)$ and put $A_{S^1} = A_{\mathbb R} \cap [0, 1)$, and similarly for $B$, so $R_\theta A_{S^1} \cap B_{S^1}$ is contained in $R_\theta A_{\mathbb R} \cap B_{\mathbb R}$ and hence has measure $0$; and […](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1157542)

Comment: […](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1157541) if we have a partition of $S^1$, then we can put $A_{\mathbb R} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z} (n + A_{S^1})$, and similarly for $B$, so $R_\theta A_{\mathbb R} \cap B_{\mathbb R}$ is contained in $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z} \bigl(n + (R_{\theta - \lfloor\theta\rfloor}A_{S^1} \cap B_{S^1}) \cup (R_{\theta - \lceil\theta\rceil}A_{S^1} \cap B_{S^1})\bigr)$ and hence has measure $0$. Or maybe I made a computational mistake, but hopefully something like that.

Comment: @LSpice :  What are $A_{\mathbb R}$ and $R_\theta A_{\mathbb R}$?

Comment: @TerryTao : A bit more generally, we have $\nu(x^{-1}A\cap B)>0$ for some $x\in G$ given $\mu_+(A)>0$ and $\nu(B)>0$, where $G$ is any locally compact group, $\mu_+$ is a right-translation-invariant Haar measure on $G$, $\nu$ is any Borel measure on $G$,  and $A$ and $B$ are any Borel subsets of $G$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1157543), I assumed the generalised question was: given loc.cpt. group $G$, does there exist a partition of $G$ into 2 non-null sets $A_G$ and $B_G$ such that $\mu_G(R_\theta A_G \cap B_G)=0$ for all $\theta\in G$, where $R_\theta A=A\cdot\theta^{-1}$? I proposed a construction of $(A_{\mathbb R},B_{\mathbb R})$ (i.e., a solution for $\mathbb R$) from $(A_{S^1}, B_{S^1})$ (i.e., a solution for $S^1$), and conversely. I definitely made at least one computational mistake, and quite possibly a conceptual one; it's just a naïve approach.

Comment: @LSpice TerryTao's comment already shows that in such a case $A_G$ and $B_G$ cannot be measurable. (That, of course, solves the case for all discrete groups.) I also believe his answer is more an answer for $\mathbb{R}$ that quotients down to $S^1$, so that solves both cases. Though your proposed way to obtain a solution for $S^1$ from a solution for $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't seem to work if the solution for $\mathbb{R}$ does not feature sets that are periodic. (But maybe if we consider $S^1$ as the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ something like that might work?)

Comment: @DavidGao, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1157548), I did [mention](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1157541) that it was probably uninteresting after @‍TerryTao's comment, but just wanted to respond to a question that was asked before that comment. I think that the construction works even for non-periodic sets, although when justifying it I should have said $(A_{S^1} +_{S^1} \theta) \cap B_{S^1} \subseteq \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z} (A_{\mathbb R} +_{\mathbb R} \theta + n) \cap B$, which still has measure $0$.  (I only noticed after the edit window, so couldn't fix it.)

Comment: @LSpice That seems right. Though we probably still need to alter the definitions of $A_{S^1}$ and $B_{S^1}$ a bit, as we could have $A_{S^1} = A \cap [0, 1)$ or $B_{S^1} = B \cap [0, 1)$ is null. Since it cannot be the case that the intersection of $A$ with any interval is null as $A$ is not null and similarly for $B$, we could replace $[0, 1)$ by a large enough interval in the definition to fix the issue.